# Checking if navigation property is null Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a model which contains a User. Each user must have a Person record. A person record may or may not have an Address record.

When I fetch the currently logged in User's address I am currently using the following which to me seems incredibly messy. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public Address GetAddress()
    {
        using (eziTraceEntities db = new eziTraceEntities())
        {
            if (db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == Globals.UserID).FirstOrDefault().Person.Address != null)
                return db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == Globals.UserID).FirstOrDefault().Person.Address;
            else
                return new Address();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
using (eziTraceEntities db = new eziTraceEntities())
    {
        return db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == Globals.UserID).FirstOrDefault().Person.Address ?? new Address();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that!